# Add Tuple2 to a scala list

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have the following scala code, which tries to add a (String, Int) tuple to a list.

```
val myTupleList: List[(String,Int)] = List()

     for (record <- recordList) {
         val nameKey = record.getName()
         myTupleList.add((nameKey,1))
     }
```

---

However, I got the following error at the line myTupleList.add((nameKey,1)).

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
```

Am I missing anything here? Thanks!

Comment: Given that "add" doesn't exist in `scala.collection.immutable.List` (and thus does not compile), and that the error called out `java.util.AbstractList`, it seems like we need some import statements to understand what a `List` really is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List` (`scala.collection.immutable.List`) is *immutable*. Instead, use a *mutable* construct, like `ListBuffer`

For example:

```
scala> val buf = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[(String,Int)]
buf  : scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(String, Int)] = ListBuffer()
scala> buf += (("test", 1))   
res0: test.buf.type = ListBuffer((test,1))
```

[Here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-mutable-collection-classes.html), you can see a overview of mutable collections.

Comment: This does not address the problem described.  `List` is not `scala.collection.immutable.List`.  See my comment on the post.  And on the other two answers that went this way.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a java.util.AbstractList[Record] and you want a scala.collection.immutable.List[(String, Int)].  Why not try the map function instead?  To quote the scala docs, the map function:

> Builds a new collection by applying a function to all elements of this collection.

First we need to get JavaConversions into scope, to implicitly convert the java collection to a scala collection (a scala.collection.mutable.Buffer to be exact):

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
```

Now that we have those in scope, the map function will be available to us.  Here we take our record object and return a tuple.  We follow that with a .toList call to get the scala collection type we want:

```
val myTupleList: List[(String,Int)] = recordList.map {
  record =>
    val nameKey = record.getName()
    (nameKey, 1)
}.toList
```

Or we can chop it down a bit and use the Arrow function "->" that builds a Tuple2:

```
val myTupleList: List[(String,Int)] = recordList.map(record => record.getName -> 1).toList
```

Or write it even more concisely with a function placeholder:

```
val myTupleList: List[(String,Int)] = recordList.map(_.getName() -> 1).toList
```

Comment: "_I think this word (List) does not mean what you think it means_." - I. Montoya

Comment: Thanks @EdStaub.  Edited my answer to properly handle the initial collection type.

Comment: The evidence shows that the _output_ `myTupleList` type is something built on java.util.AbstractList.  The input list type is moot, though I'd guess it probably is a scala collection, since it has a foreach, as evidenced by `record <- recordList` compiling.  I assume the OP needs the "`List`" output type - whatever the heck it is.

Answer (score 0):

`List()` in Scala are immutable - `add` operations are not supported. You might want to look into `scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList`.

Comment: Probably irrelevant - see comment above.